# onChange event affects to the entire form

Tags: javascript, user-interface, uitextfield, onchange, webix

There's a short Webix form, and I'm trying to highlight the field which value has changed, but I'm stuck with this.

Here's my code:

```
    webix.ui({
      view:"form",   
      width: 250,
      elements: [  
        { view:"text", label:'Phone', labelPosition: "top", name:"phone", value: "" },   
        { view:"text", label:'Email', labelPosition: "top", name:"email", value:"" },
      ],
        on:{
          onChange: function(newv, oldv){           
            webix.html.addCss(this.getNode(), "new_v");         
          }
        }   
    });
```

The snippet: http://webix.com/snippet/b47894fa

As you can see, the `onChange` event affects to each field, no matter which of them have new values. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the source of onChange event by using `this.$eventSource`

```
  onChange: function(newv, oldv){           
    var source = this.$eventSource;
    webix.html.addCss(source.getNode(), "new_v");           
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ValVert's idea of using individual event handlers is good, but you don't need to repeat the same event handling code in each view. You can use the form's [elementsConfig](https://docs.webix.com/desktop__common_config.html) property to define the `onChange` handler once. Here's your example, [cleaned up](https://snippet.webix.com/4yjdlibp). Type stuff in the form, and press Enter.

```js
webix.ui({
  view: 'form',   
  width: 250,
  elementsConfig: {
    labelPosition: 'top',
    on: {
      onChange: function(newv, oldv) {
        webix.html.addCss(this.getNode(), 'new_v');
      }
    }
  },
  elements: [  
    { view: "text", label: 'Phone', name: 'phone' },   
    { view: "text", label: 'Email', name: 'email' },
  ],
});
```

```css
.new_v input {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the event to each text and not to the form.

```
webix.ui({
  view:"form",   
  width: 250,
  elements: [  
    { view:"text", label:'Phone', labelPosition: "top", name:"phone", value: "",
      on:
      {
          onChange: function(newv, oldv){           
          webix.html.addCss(this.getNode(), "new_v");         
        }
      }
    },   
    { view:"text", label:'Email', labelPosition: "top", name:"email", value:"" ,
      on:
      {
          onChange: function(newv, oldv){           
          webix.html.addCss(this.getNode(), "new_v");         
        }
      }
    },
  ]   
});
```

Comment: You can use [elementsConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57680074/1269037) to define the onChange only once.